# Get Row Count with Group By statement SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and navicat. I need to get Row Count in a table using SQL. The problem is that I am using Group By statement and my result is :

[image]

I need Sum of rcount value, the same like RowCount without Group By statement.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want this as an additional column, you can do this using window functions:

```
select count(*) as rcount, goalarea,
       sum(count(*)) over () as TotalCount
from table t
group by goalarea;
```

If you want it as a separate row, I would use `with rollup`:

```
select count(*) as rcount, goalarea
from table t
group by goalarea with rollup;
```

(You can also use `grouping sets`, but I find `with rollup` easier for this simple problem.)

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon! When writing queries with 5 Joins during 8 hours per day, sometimes forget about realy child things :)